# Unable to install Google Chrome

Tags: 10.10, google-chrome

I receive this in my terminal when I try to install using

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*
```

or

```
sudo dpkg --install /Path/to/chrome.deb
```

I receive

```
Selecting previously unselected package google-chrome-stable.
(Reading database ... 146911 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking google-chrome-stable (from google-chrome-stable_current_i386.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of google-chrome-stable:
  google-chrome-stable depends on xdg-utils (>= 1.0.2).

dpkg: error processing google-chrome-stable (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 google-chrome-stable
```

I then type

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

And retry installation though it still does not install and I receive the same errors.  I have also tried using:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1 libnspr4-0d libcurl3
```

Though the above doesn't work either.

Comment: Can you post the output of the `sudo apt-get install -f` as that's where the errors will be. The errors in `dpkg` are expected.

Comment: You can also do `sudo apt-get update` beforehand to ensure apt as a fully up-to-date list of packages in case it needs to find dependencies that have updated since the last time you ran apt. (i.e. apt is only aware of `xdg-utils=1.0.0`)

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you're experiencing stems from the fact that you're downloading a package manually and instead of using apt-get to install it, you're using dpkg, which doesn't automatically resolve the dependencies and doesn't install them before the deb package.

Try first installing the package dpkg complains about:

```
sudo apt-get install xdg-utils
```

and then install the Chrome deb package with dpkg, the same way you tried earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing Chrome using Google's repository. This can be done two ways.

### Simple Way

You can run this bash script, which just wraps the hard way up in a nutshell.

```
wget http://mtweb.site90.com/files/chrome.sh
bash chrome.sh
```

For more info, see [Millhousen Tech's Tech-To](http://mtweb.site90.com/tech-tos/install-chrome-linux-terminal/).

### Long Way

The bash script contains the following commands that you can run. (Exact same as simple way, just longer.)

```
wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | sudo apt-key add -
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-chrome.list'
sudo apt-get update
```

You can then choose what version of Chrome you want to install. Stable, Beta, or Unstable. (Run one of the following commands.)

```
sudo apt-get install google-chrome-stable

sudo apt-get install google-chrome-beta

sudo apt-get install google-chrome-unstable
```

For more info, see [How Open Source's website](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/10/install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-11-10-11-04-10-10-10-04/).

Comment: I dont think that downloading a script from some site and running it would be considered "installing using the PPA"

Comment: The bash script just simplifies the process. I added the long way to be clear.

Comment: Its all good, the script is fine but it just seems like sending someone to a link rather than explaining what the link does. I reversed my down vote.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu ships chromium ( chrome's non google branded cousin) in the repository, and since it's blessed by Canonical, when you install it, it will fix and install the needed dependencies. If it is just for browsing, I humbly suggest using that since it has more privacy options turned on out of the box.